# How create a Debian live USB on an Ubuntu system?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, usb

I have just switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu, and I am not satisfied. Ubuntu is just as slow as Windows 10, and my computer only has 2 GB of RAM.
 I want to install Debian, because it is supposedly faster than Ubuntu. I have used the universal USB installer to create a bootable USB of Ubuntu, but this program only runs on Windows and macOS. 
How do I burn a debian iso into a USB on Ubuntu? Also if anyone has suggestions for lightweight distributions, please share

Answer (score 4):

- Unplug the USB-Stick from your computer.
- Open a terminal and become root (e.g. `sudo -i`)
- list devices with `lsblk`
- Plug your USB-Stick into your computer.
- run `lsblk` again. The new device (e.g. sdc) is you USB-Stick.
- If mounted, unmount the stick with `umount /dev/sdXY` (e.g. /dev/sdc1)
- use `dd if=/path/to/debian.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=16M`
- Unplug your USB-Stick from your computer.

Comment: I think it worked, but how do I change the boot order?

Comment: You need to look this up in your computers BIOS. With some you'll have to change the boot order, others will provide a BOOT MENU to select the drive you want to start from during system start.

Comment: I confirm that you should modify the boot order selecting the USB driver on BIOS mode. F1 or F11 or another button. it depends on your PC/server model to switch on boot mode. Let us know if you need more help :

Answer (score 0):

Go to Debian's download page, grab the image you want. Follow the instructions to create a bootable CD/DVD/USB drive. Ubuntu is (more or less) Debian, mostly the same tools should be available.